# Module 'cloud_firestore' not found - Flutter Xcode Build

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

When i started working on this Flutter app, Firebase was working until i decided to add Apple Sign in. Now when I try to run my app, a file GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m file gives me an error Module 'cloud_firestore' not found and my build fails.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRmku.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6wcT.png)

I have already tried 'flutter clean', 'flutter pub get', i've reinstalled dependencies (they're all up to date - or at least with my build config constraints), i've tried Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder, and GPT has said that i need to include ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseFirestore in Xcode > Target Runner > Build Settings > Header search path (but that doesn't exist), and if i have a custom build config, then to set Base Configuration to the Runner.profile.xcconfig but in my Runner.xcconfig i already have '#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"'

Lastly, pod install with cocoapods and i get this warning message but nobody has been able to explain the difference between '...Runner.xcconfig' that's already in my Runner.xcconfig file and '...Runner.profile.xcconfig' that Cocoapods has been telling me to include

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

What else is there to do?